# Sub grouping the data and using macro inside a loop to draw a histogram

Tags: for-loop, sas, grouping, sas-macro

I am using sas 9.4

I have a dataset 10000x7 looks like this

```
survtime cont Trial SurvI Treat PatID Sim
1 2.271536 2.6398586 1 1 0 1 1
2 2.920410 -0.1787789 1 1 0 2 1
3 1.328392 -2.1513527 1 1 0 3 1
4 11.433881 2.2132001 1 1 0 4 1
5 20.264126 0.9029487 1 0 1 5 1
6 19.827590 0.3236216 1 0 1 6 1
```

last column is 'Sim' take values 1 to 10 and changes every 1000 times,
like 1 to 1000 sim=1
1001 to 2000 sim=2
.
.
9001 to 10000 sim=10

and then I have a macro

```
%NORMSURV(data=prostate,true=survtime,trueind=survind,surrog=psa,treat=treat,center=trial,patientid=patid,copula=houggard,adjustment=weighted,imagefmt=eps);
```

I want to run this macro for each sim value and get two values TAU and R2

I like to clear a point let's say there is no 'sim', only 1000x6 I can get those values

```
proc print data=sur_measure_clay ;
VAR TAU R2;
run;
```

with running that code.

now I have 10 of them, I can do by hand but I will have 100 of them to draw a histogram 
I want to run keep those 2 values to get a histogram plot.
'data=sur_measure_clay' is a default name comes from macro.
Thank you

Comment: What is the macro doing?  Why not just tell it do all of the sims at once by just adding BY SIM to the code?

Comment: What values does `survtime` take on in the 10,000 records, or with each 1,000 comprising a sim ?

Comment: @Richard each sim (simulation) survtime is a random variable of exp(lambda) of 1000.

Comment: So would the first column (1,2,3,4,5,6) be simply row numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the proper way to do this task will be to modify your macro to do histograms through your whole dataset. 
Assuming macro %NORMSURV works as described by you, it can be done as below:

```
/*  there is no need to use proc sql
if you know how much of iteration do you have */

proc sql noprint;
    select distinct max(sim)  
        into : max_iter 
        from prostate;
    quit;

%put Maximum value of Sim Variable : &max_iter;
```

Then you can put your macro inside another loop

```
%macro sim_iterate;

    %do iter  =  1 %to &max_iter;
        data tmp;
            set prostate;
                where sim = &max_iter;
        run;

        /* Run your instructions */

    %end;
%mend;

%sim_iterate;
```

Comment: I added up doing something like this idea but longer than this. I will try if this works. I created tmp file for each iteration so I can hold the values later for histogram. It ended up working actually : ))